# File.Delete deletes file, still throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: .net-4.0, iis-7.5

In my web application, hosted by the ASP.NET v4.0 application pool in an IIS 7.5,
when deleting a file that resides in the app's so-called *physical path* (HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath), the file gets deleted, but an UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown none the less.

I've tried granting all permissions on that directory to all users (the user "Everyone", the user "ASP.NET v4.0", which should be the one that matters in IIS 7.5, to the user "NETWORK SERVICE", ...), to no avail.

Now if I change the path of the file to be deleted to either a sub directory or to any other absolute path on the disk, the file gets deleted without any exceptions.

How can I fix this?

Or is it considered bad practice for a web app to delete a file out of the physical path (even if it put it there in the first place, in my case it's a log file)?

**Update** In the meantime, I worked around it by using a sub directory for my log files, which makes sense anyway, but I'm still interested in why that exception occured and if there's a fix.

Answer (score 0):

By saying 'You gave permissions to all users' do you mean you marked the directory using the 'Everyone' user? If not check that to see if it is permissions based error as it could be the fun windows UAC. UAC stops you writing to certain folders without giving permission.

If it works once you have set the permission to everyone, check to see what user account the application pool is running under and try granting permissions to that account.

Comment: I gave all permissions to Everyone, as well as to the "ASP.NET v4.0" user, for the directory the file is in. That said, I don't believe it is a user permission issue, otherwise the file would not be deleted. Plus with the same permissions, it works in directories other than the project's physical path.